# Empty collection returns single object in spring data rest instead of empty array

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am using spring data rest for my application.

I have disabled to hal json type by using the following:-

```
 @Override
 public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

  config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
}
```

My response looks like the following for empty object:-

```
{

    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/users"
        },
        {
            "rel": "profile",
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/profile/users"
        },
        {
            "rel": "search",
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/search"
        }
    ],
    "content": [
        {
            "relTargetType": "com.sample.User",
            "collectionValue": true,
            "value": [ ]
        }
    ]

}
```

When I have data for user, It looks like the following:-

```
links": [

    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://localhost:8081/users"
    },
    {
        "rel": "profile",
        "href": "http://localhost:8081/profile/users"
    },
    {
        "rel": "search",
        "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/search"
    }

],
"content": [

    {
        "id": 2,
        "key": "wire",
        "name": "Wireless",
        "content": [ ],
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/2"
            },
            {
                "rel": "user",
                "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/2"
            }
        ]
    }..
```

My concern is to have empty content collection like as below:-

```
{

    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/users"
        },
        {
            "rel": "profile",
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/profile/users"
        },
        {
            "rel": "search",
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/users/search"
        }
    ],
    "content": []

}
```

How can I handle empty collection in spring data rest ? Kindly help me

Comment: could you include the repository method you are invoking? or have you found a solution?

Comment: Was there any solution?